# Applescript: can't make file "xx" into type <<class fsrf>>

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to get a script working which is able to batch export .mts format video files via quicktime into .mov files in 1080p. The script fails with the following error: "The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “QuickTime Player got an error: Can’t make file (document "00000.MTS") into type «class fsrf».”". I assume this has something to do with using text file paths? Note I'm not experienced with Applescript and would really appreciate any help to get this simple bit of script working. Currently it's in automator as a service:

```
on run {inputFiles}
if inputFiles is equal to {} then
    set inputFiles to (choose file with prompt "Select the file(s) to convert:" with multiple selections allowed without invisibles)
end if
open inputFiles
end run

on open droppedItems
tell application "Finder" to set inputFolder to (container of first item of droppedItems) as Unicode text
set outputFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Select output folder:" default location (inputFolder as alias)) as Unicode text

set exportPreset to (choose from list {"Movie", "iPhone", "iPod", "480p", "720p", "1080p"} with prompt "Choose QuickTime Export Preset:") as Unicode text
if exportPreset is equal to "false" then
    return
end if

repeat with currentItem in droppedItems
    repeat until getProcessPercentCPU("CoreMediaAuthoringSessionHelper") is equal to ""
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder" to set fileName to name of currentItem as Unicode text
    set fileName to text 1 thru ((fileName's length) - (offset of "." in ¬
        (the reverse of every character of fileName) as text)) of fileName
    convertFile(currentItem, outputFolder & fileName & ".mov", exportPreset)
end repeat
end open

on convertFile(inputFile, outputFile, exportPreset)

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set thisMovie to open inputFile
    open for access file thisMovie
    close access file thisMovie
    export thisMovie in (outputFile) using settings preset exportPreset
    close thisMovie
end tell
end convertFile

on getProcessPercentCPU(processName)
do shell script "/bin/ps -xco %cpu,command | /usr/bin/awk '/" & processName & "$/ {print $1}'"
end getProcessPercentCPU
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
set outputFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Select output folder:" default location (inputFolder as alias)) as Unicode text
```

to:

```
set outputFolder to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Select output folder:" default location (inputFolder as alias))
```

and:

```
convertFile(currentItem, outputFolder & fileName & ".mov", exportPreset)
```

to:

```
set outputFile to POSIX file (outputFolder & fileName & ".mov")
convertFile(currentItem, outputFile, exportPreset)
```

and remove the `open for access`/`close access commands`.

Sandboxed apps don't like receiving path strings to `open`/`save` commands, but accept `alias`/`POSIX file` values okay. (If it still doesn't work then it's some other issue at play, but that's always the first thing to check when you get a filesystem permissions error as you describe.)

Comment: Wow, absolutely stellar help thanks! Works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because `thisMovie` is a document reference of `QuickTime Player` and this class cannot be converted / coerced to a `file system reference` («class fsrf»).

That's what the error message says

> Can’t make file (document "00000.MTS") into type «class fsrf»

The Standard Additions command `open for access` does not support `QuickTime Player` documents anyway. What is the purpose of the open / close lines?

Note:

`as Unicode text` as coercion to string is outdated since macOS 10.5 Leopard. It's only used with `read` and `write` commands to handle UTF16 encoded text. A coercion to standard AppleScript text is simply written `as text`. In case of `name of currentItem` it's redundant anyway because the class of `name` is always `text`.

Comment: The access lines were an addition as prior to them I was receiving permission errors: the script came up with the error "You don’t have permission to save the file “xxx.mov” in the folder “xxx”. You don’t have permission." Without understanding the fundamentals I assumed it might be a quick fix - which apparently it isn't. Any ideas on fixing the script?

Comment: If you need the lines you have to use `inputFile`:  `open for access inputFile` (without `file`)